# Qlik sense 2 condition string

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to make an if statement:

```
if(product = 'a', 'red', if(city = 'south', 'red', 'green')
```

This returns green only. I want it to return red and green

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say whether there's an issue with your data, the expression, or your logic without seeing your data, but here is a screenshot that explains a few different scenarios for your `If()` expression:

[image: Screenshot of a Qlik Sense table showing the results on an If expression]

Make sure you are using the `If()` function correctly -- if it's not returning what you're expecting it to based on your intended logic, maybe consider adding in some [`AND` and `OR` operators](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/Operators/LogicalOperators.htm) as needed to apply the correct logic to the expression. You can also see some more examples of using the `If()` function on [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/if.htm).

Feel free to edit your question with an example of your data if you have further questions!